# MySQL diff timestamps of certain row pairs and disregard all other rows

Tags: mysql

I've got a mysql table served by a broken app with several million rows that has pointless login/logouts.  The app can't be fixed at the moment, so I am trying to write a query that diffs the time (in seconds) between any and all pairs of timestamps (in a not-shown date range) that match 'agentlogin' preceded by an 'agentlogout' row while disregarding all other rows not meeting that criteria.

I've been searching on this site for many hours and though I have found a few good query examples, they only work on tables (served by well-written apps) that have logins followed by logouts and none of this duplicate stuff.

Here's the table:

```
+---------+---------------------+-------+-------------+------------------+
| id      | calldate            | agent | etype       | uniqueid         |
+---------+---------------------+-------+-------------+------------------+
| 1838073 | 2017-11-02 13:21:00 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509628860.54414 |
| 1838232 | 2017-11-02 14:46:19 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509633979.54881 |
| 1838323 | 2017-11-02 15:27:50 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509636470.55125 |
| 1838373 | 2017-11-02 15:51:04 | 503   | agentlogin  | 1509637864.55274 |
| 1838385 | 2017-11-02 15:55:57 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509638157.55318 |
| 1838460 | 2017-11-02 16:28:52 | 503   | agentlogin  | 1509640132.55533 |
| 1838472 | 2017-11-02 16:35:23 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509640523.55564 |
| 1838499 | 2017-11-02 16:42:35 | 503   | agentlogin  | 1509640954.55630 |
| 1838567 | 2017-11-02 17:16:02 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509642962.55820 |
| 1838686 | 2017-11-02 18:04:17 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509645857.56162 |
| 1838861 | 2017-11-02 19:48:59 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509652139.56778 |
| 1838896 | 2017-11-02 20:11:37 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509653497.56914 |
+---------+---------------------+-------+-------------+------------------+
```

In short, I'm trying to get a total sum of seconds between all matching pairs.  The closest I've come is

```
SELECT round(e2.uniqueid - e1.uniqueid) as seconds
FROM dumbtable e1
LEFT JOIN dumbtable e2
  ON e1.agent = e2.agent AND e2.etype ='agentlogoff' AND e1.calldate < e2.calldate
LEFT JOIN dumbtable e3
  ON e1.agent = e3.agent AND e1.calldate < e3.calldate AND e3.calldate < e2.calldate
WHERE e1.agent = '503' and e1.etype='agentlogin'
GROUP BY e1.agent;
```

... but this only diffs the seconds of the first matching pairs and nothing else.

```
+---------+
| seconds |
+---------+
|     293 |
+---------+
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT:

See comments, (thanks walter for solving the first problem!) I had forgotten to show an example that catches both problems.  In addition to solving for only a login pair with a login followed immediately by a logout, I need to compare only the first instance of login with the next instance of logout regardless of login rows in between. To attempt to describe more clearly, if there is a

0 logout -> 1 login -> 2 login -> 3 login -> 4 logout -> 5 logout -> 6 logout -> login, etc

I want to "pair" and timediff the earliest login (1) with the very next logout (4) and disregard 2,3,5,6.   I hope this makes sense, and it is how I should have formulated my original question. Basically, the only legitimate timestamps in this table each earliest login followed by the next earliest logout.

Here's an example with the multiple login rows as well.  Arrows are the legitimate entries that I need the timediff in seconds, everything else should be disregarded.

```
+---------+---------------------+-------+-------------+------------------+
| id      | calldate            | agent | etype       | uniqueid         |
+---------+---------------------+-------+-------------+------------------+
| 1838073 | 2017-11-02 13:21:00 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509628860.54414 |x
| 1838232 | 2017-11-02 14:46:19 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509633979.54881 |x
| 1838323 | 2017-11-02 15:27:50 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509636470.55125 |x
| 1838373 | 2017-11-02 15:51:04 | 503   | agentlogin  | 1509637864.55274 |<--in
| 1838374 | 2017-11-02 15:52:04 | 503   | agentlogin  | 1509637866.55274 |x
| 1838375 | 2017-11-02 15:53:04 | 503   | agentlogin  | 1509637867.55274 |x
| 1838385 | 2017-11-02 15:55:57 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509638157.55318 |<--out
| 1838460 | 2017-11-02 16:28:52 | 503   | agentlogin  | 1509640132.55533 |<--in
| 1838472 | 2017-11-02 16:35:23 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509640523.55564 |<--out
| 1838499 | 2017-11-02 16:42:35 | 503   | agentlogin  | 1509640954.55630 |<--in
| 1838567 | 2017-11-02 17:16:02 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509642962.55820 |<--out
| 1838686 | 2017-11-02 18:04:17 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509645857.56162 |x
| 1838861 | 2017-11-02 19:48:59 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509652139.56778 |x
| 1838896 | 2017-11-02 20:11:37 | 503   | agentlogoff | 1509653497.56914 |x
+---------+---------------------+-------+-------------+------------------+
```

Also, I hope I'm not breaking the rules by starting a question, getting a perfect answer, then changing the question.  Sorry!!!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Erik I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've met these kind of demands for serveral times recently. Here is my aprroach:

If your `id` field has an auto-increment option, the statement below may help you out:

```
SELECT round(uniqueid2 - uniqueid1) AS seconds 
FROM
(
  SELECT uniqueid AS uniqueid1, 
         (SELECT uniqueid FROM dumbtable WHERE agent = '503' AND etype = 'agentlogoff' AND id > t1.id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) AS uniqueid2 
  FROM dumbtable AS t1 WHERE agent = '503' AND etype = 'agentlogin'
) AS t;
```

The key points here are:

- use a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) so that you can do it repeatly for every `agentlogin` record.
- use the auto-increment `id` column and a `limit 1` substatement to find out the accurate next-matched row( `agentlogoff` here). The auto-increment field is not essential here, you also can use `calldate` in this case.

---

For the second question:
If I were you I would backup the table, delete all the invalid records, and then just run the first query I gave you. It is easy to understand, easy to accomplish, also runs faster.

To delete invalid records:

```
DELETE 
FROM dumbtable AS t1 
WHERE etype = (SELECT etype FROM dumbtable WHERE id < t1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Of course I can give you another query to do this job, but it would be very complicated, and super slow.

Comment: In what sense is the 'next matched row' 'next'?

Comment: @Strawberry He wants to find out all `login-logoff` pairs here. `next-matched row` means the corresponding `logoff` for every `login`. Maybe I didn't express myself clearly. Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure? I've run this query on my own table, and it works for me. Actually my query returns difference of each pair.

Comment: @walter - Your query works perfectly with data like the example I provided you, so thanks for that!  Unfortunately I forgot that in other instances they also have multiple rows with agentlogin, as well, and of course I want to catch only the first instance of agentlogin and skip the repeated ones in between.  Regardless, you solved the problem as I presented it, so again, thank you!!!

Comment: @Erik Sorry, I got confused by your new question. What do the `other instances` and `the first instance` mean? Could you redescribe it with more details?

Comment: @walter - I went ahead and added an additional description at the bottom of my original question post.  This is definitely a broken app and table, so thanks if you want to have a go at it!

Comment: OK, I'll take a look at it tomorrow, it's really too late today.